# My xslt not produce correct output?

Tags: xml, xslt

My XML is 'input.xsl'

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
     <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="input.xsl"?>
      <catalog>
     <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>CBS Records</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1988</year>
    </cd>
       </catalog>
```

Now I want to generate another XML document using the above XML file with help of XSLT as following,(OUTPUT format)

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
        <catalog>
        <cd>
       <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
       <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        </cd>
        <cd>
       <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        </cd>
          </catalog>
```

For that I create xsl file, 'input.xsl'

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="catalog">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="catalog/cd/title"/> <br/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="catalog/cd/artist"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="catalog/cd/artist">
        <xsl:element name="cd">
            <xsl:value-of select="current()"/> 
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="catalog/cd/title">
        <xsl:element name="cd">
            <xsl:value-of select="current()"/> 
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

The above xsl file does not produce the output in xml format. so what is the problem in my code. Guide me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You're consuming the paths you are intending to match on, in the select clause of your  invocation. Remember, as each node is matched, it becomes the *current* node from which any subsequent relative XPath expressions are evaluated. Also, you don't need to construct elements via  all the time - just put the 'boilerplate' XML where you want it.

I suggest instead:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <catalog><xsl:apply-templates /></catalog>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cd">
     <cd><xsl:apply-templates /></cd>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="artist">
    <artist><xsl:value-of select="text()" /></artist>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="title">
    <title><xsl:value-of select="text()" /></title>
</xsl:template>
```

I can't remember if text() is the right thing, but that might get you heading in the right direction.

Comment: +1 Yes I think this explains the current node concept in a helpful way

Comment: Built-in rule for text nodes output the string value. So all your rules are the same rule `<xsl:template match="title|artist|cd|catalog"> <xsl:copy> <xsl:apply-templates/> </xsl:copy> </xsl:template>`. But you need to add the stripping rules because built-in rule for elements (in this case `cd` chlidren others than `title` or `artist`) apply templates to children.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I didn't think you would need all that template matching. It seems to make it more difficult because the context is different each time.

I would just match on the root, and do a for-each on the cd element. 
Seems so much simpler, I think you'll understand just from reading it ;-)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <catalog>
            <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
                <cd>
                    <title><xsl:value-of select="title"/></title>
                    <artist><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></artist>
                </cd>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </catalog>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: And if we go down this path, you could just `<xsl:copy-of select="title|artist">`

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, exploiting the identity transform pattern.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="country | company | price | year | processing-instruction()"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to the sample XML, correct result is produced:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

Comment: But you don't need to remove PIs -- there aren't any present. If you do, then probably you should remove comment nodes too?

Comment: @Dimitre, there is xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="input.xsl".

Comment: +1 Good answer. I would use reverse logic here like an empty template matching this pattern `cd/*[not(self::title|self::artist)]` , or this `cd/*` and other with `cd/title|cd/artist` with more `@priority`...